# Understanding "-ㄹ 정도면"

Tags: grammar, translation

> 네가 작아보일 정도면 친구들이 걸리버야

A family member wrote this sentence to me after seeing a photo of me with some friends. From the 'Gulliver' reference I think the sentence means something like 'your friends must be really tall if they make you look short'. 작아보이다 is 'look small', I think. However, I'm still not quite understanding the grammar of the '작아보일 정도면' bit. Has something been omitted for brevity?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

'~ 정도면 (이면) ~ 이다 (하다)' is a rhetorical device for emphasis. For example:

> 네가 미스 코리아 대회 나갈 정도면 난 미스 유니버스다. If you are pretty enough to participate in Miss Korea Beauty Pageant, I am Miss Universe.

This sentence jokingly means "Sorry, you are not that pretty." or "I am far more beautiful than you think you are."

'[정도](http://krdic.naver.com/search.nhn?query=%EC%A0%95%EB%8F%84&kind=all)' means 'degree' or 'extent'. Your example sentence is literally translated to:

> (너의 친구들 키가 커서) 네가 작아보일 정도면 친구들이 걸리버야 If you look short (because your friends are extremely tall), your friends are Gulliver.

This sentence means

> You are not that short. Your friends are extraordinarily tall. That's
>   why they make you look short in the picture.

The sentence could be rephrased without using the noun *정도*.

> 네가 작아보인다면 친구들이 (친구들은) 걸리버야.

Another similar expression:

> 네가 국회의원이면 나는 대통령이다. If you are a member of the National Assembly,   I am the President.

This sentence means "I know you are bluffing about your position". "Don't give me that bull shit. I know you are not what you say you are."

You can make similar sentences using this construction.

> 네가 경찰이면 나는 국회의원이다. If you are a policeman, I am a member of the
>   National Assembly.
>
> 네가 부자면 나는 빌 게이츠다. If you are rich, I am a Bill Gates.